# Add embedded texture to Assimp matrial

Tags: c++, export, assimp

I want to add texture to my material and export it.

I added texture to `scene->mTextures`. and my question is how can I add this texture reference to my material?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the texture with its type to the material definition. For instance if you want to add a Diffuse-Texture you need to add the texture name , its relation for the UV-source-mapping and the requested clamp-mode:

```
aiMaterial *mat = new aiMaterial;
mat->AddProperty( diffuseTexture.c_str(), 1, AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE_DIFFUSE(0) );
int uvwIndex=0;
mat->AddProperty( &uvwIndex, 1, AI_MATKEY_UVWSRC_DIFFUSE(0) );
mat->AddProperty<int>( &clampMode, 1, AI_MATKEY_MAPPINGMODE_U( aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0) );
```

The UV-mapping and clamp-mode will have some default values, so specifying this is just for special configurations. See [ObjImporter](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/ObjFileImporter.cpp#L623)

For exporting just look into the examples or the documentation.